# Access collection from MongoDB using Nextjs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

New to NextJs

I want to access data from a collection "users" from my mongoDB and display the data as a component.

I'm using NextJs and mongoose

I created an API and tested it - works well (tested using Postman).

/app/api/users/route.js

```
import connectMongoDB from "src/lib/mongodb.ts";
import User from "@/app/models/User";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  await connectMongoDB();
  console.log("Connected from GET");
  const usersList = await User.find();
  return NextResponse.json({ usersList });
}
```

I've created a component called MembersList.tsx

```
import getMembers from "@/lib/getMembers";

export default async function MemberList() {
  const members: any = await getMembers();
  return members;
}
```

I've created getMembers() function that calls the API and returns the list as JSON as follows:

/lib/getMembers.tsx

```
export default async function getMembers() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/users", {
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  if (!res.ok) throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  return res.json();
}
```

My user model / schema looks like this

/app/models/User.ts

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  email: String,
  name: String,
});

const User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```

My question is - what purpose does the schema play in this case?

I found that by deleting the contents of the schema and having it empty, it still works...

However, if I remove the schema all together, I get an error about a schema not being registerd to the User model.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In short, everything in Mongoose is derived from the Schema. You need to pass a Schema to the `mongoose.model()` function in order to create a Model of your data. Without a Schema you can't model your data. Consequently, you can't perform CRUD operations on your MongoDB collections with Mongoose. You can use other tools, just not Mongoose.

There is a distinction to be made between Mongoose and MongoDB. Due to it's flexibility you can have an almost infinite number of different document structures inside the same MongoDB collection. It will make life more difficult having lots of different structures but MongoDB will allow it. However, with Mongoose, your Schema defines a finite set of properties and data types that each document must or must not conform to. That makes life easier by having a consistent way of doing CRUD operations, because each document was modelled on the Schema.

What you have found is that the Schema can be as verbose or concise as you please, just as long as one is provided. An empty Schema means a document without any properties other than the default `_id` and `__v` that Mongoose adds, both of which can be disabled. There is an option to set `{strict: false}` to the Schema, which will give you a free flowing Schema in case your documents change structure dynamically over time. You can read about that [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) but I personally don't have any experience with it and expect there to be some downsides.

A well defined Schema means you have available to you; built in data type validation, uniqueness, custom error messaging, indexing, casting and hooks to name but a few. By defining the properties and their data types it means Mongoose will create documents that only match your schema and add a whole bunch of nice features for interacting with those properties because Mongoose now knows what they will look like. Lastly, if you try and add a property that's not in your Schema Mongoose will just ignore it.